# matisse theme show excerpts not whole content

Tags: theme-development, content, excerpt

I want to only show the excerpts, not the entire content,

This question has been asked and answered in respect of the twenty eleven theme.

Matisse theme is different. where can i find the files to alter content to excerpts

Comment: I added the answer here. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/319861/how-to-just-show-first-line-of-content/319864#319864

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the Matisse theme, but start by looking at `loop.php` and see if you can find `the_content();` in there somewhere. If so, swap it out for `the_excerpt();` and see if it shows up as expected.

If that's the answer you need, check out the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) in the Codex to find other files that are outputting the full post where you want an excerpt.