# How to just show first line of content

Tags: content

is it possible to show only the first line of content `<?php the_content(); ?>` or alternative only content between `<b>text</b>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could also do something like:

```
function rt_before_after($content) {

 $replace = "</b>";
 $shortcontent = strstr($content, $replace, true).$replace;

 if ($shortcontent === false) $shortcontent = $content;

    return $shortcontent;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'rt_before_after');
```

It should look for the first `</b>` in your content and return everything before that.  it then adds the `</b>` back.  The function takes that string and replaces your content.

Comment: tried it, however this somehow breaks the hole site :-(

Comment: did you add the if statement?  what is the error on your site?

Comment: the site is empty after the code. Maybe I made a mistake. Your code belong in the function file right? how do I show the shortcontent? Still with '<?php the_content(); ?>'?

Comment: Yes in functions file.  I added error check above.  looks like it doesn't like html codes.  It works if you add a word that is actually in the page, but not with html.  Sorry

Comment: confirming working as well :-)

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is work with this `the_excerpt()` change this instead of `the_content();`

And give the amount of words that you want, add this in functions.php after you add the_excerpt();

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

More info here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/

After that force the first line, using this for example.

```
.post p {
    width: 100px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

add the width of the content.(even if its responsive just change the css as you want).

Comment: Thanks, I know that however ist not about the amount of words its about the first line (sometimes these line has only 2 Words sometimes 10)

Comment: Thanks again, however even if its works partial it still shows the content only hidden and therefore visible for search engines ;-)

Comment: Also excerpts is taking the formatting <p> <b> away.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution! I use this code:

```
    function awesome_excerpt($text, $raw_excerpt) {
    if( ! $raw_excerpt ) {
        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
        $text = substr( $content, 0, strpos( $content, '</p>' ) + 4 );
    }
        return $text;
}
add_filter( 'wp_trim_excerpt', 'awesome_excerpt', 10, 2 );
```

and than use `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>`